# Search Functionality in windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, search, listbox

Please tell me how to search the items in windows Phone 7?

Having 4 `listboxes` I am binding the items based on listbox id to that `listboxes` ,placed one search textbox if whenever enter letter in that textbox need to display matching items.

Please tell me how to acheieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't really understand what you're asking...

... but if you are only looking at searching on one letter, then the long list selector might be useful: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api

... and if you want to search on more free text, then the autocomplete control might be of use http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/autocompletebox-for-wp7-in-depth

Both of these are open source code in the SL toolkit for wp7